# Difference between, "claimed as" and "claimed to be"

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between:

> "She claimed the child as her own"

and:

> "She claimed the child to be her own"

Answer (score 6):

Claim has two meanings.

In the first use it means that she is saying that the object (now) belongs to her.

(Example: "The explorer planted the flag and claimed the country for the Queen of England")

In the second use, it means that she is stating that she believes something is the case

(Example: "John claimed he knew nothing about the missing money").

In the above example they could mean the same thing (except in some edge cases such as 'claiming' the child by kidnapping him for the first case)

Answer (score 2):

**"Claimed ... to be"** involves making a verbal statement, for example, by speaking or writing the statement in order to communicate her belief that she has a parental rights over the child. This can be as simple as answering "yes" to the question "is this your child?"

**"Claimed ... as"** is broader and stronger than just making a verbal statement. It often has the connotation of **taking some action** based on her belief about her parental rights. It may include making a statement like in "claimed to be", but I think it often means taking action that demonstrates a commitment to the fact being true. An example might be filing court papers to assert custody.

Answer (score 1):

> She claimed the child as her own

In this example the child wasn't the woman's, but she is now taking it to be.

> She claimed the child to be her own

In this example the child is the woman's and she is attempting to make that known.

---

The meanings of "claimed as" and "claimed to be" will vary depending on circumstance. Sometimes, as shown in your examples, "claimed as" means "is since" and "claimed to be" means "is". Other times "claimed to be" can be used to infer uncertainty regarding claim validity while "claimed as" yields no opposition to a claim.

> This land is claimed as part of Uivinio territory.

It is since claim.

> This land is claimed to be Uivinio territory.

It may be.

Comment: As I wrote this I kept writing "clam to be" :P .